# Can't add more items in dropdown

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I made a dropdown but can't add more than three items.

Although if I remove overflow:hidden tag I can add more items but I used this tag to remove bullets and for the dropdown to open and close.

```css
.slide {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .4s ease;
}
 .slide li {padding : 20px;}

 #touch {position: absolute; opacity: 0; height: 0;}
 #touch:checked + .slide {height: 200px;}
```

```html
<ul class="slide">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Take a look [how overflow works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: You don't need to have overflow: hidden to remove the bullets. You can use list-style-type: none; instead and do the same thing, and then find some other way to open and close your dropdown menu with JS

Comment: In your styling, you mentioned height as 0 pixels. May I know the reason if it is necessary? Or you can modify the code. According to me height: 0px and overflow:hidden; affect your functionality.

Comment: @RutikPatel I set the height to 0 pixels for the dropdown to close

Answer (score 1):

Sum the `line-height` (default ~1.2 x font-size) and `padding` (x2 for top/bottom) of your `li` elements.

You will see that only three `li` will fit in `.slide { height: 200px }`

**=>** `1.2 * 16px * 3 + 40px * 3 = 177.6px`. Adding top padding `20px` for the fourth `li`, totalling `197.6`, which yields just enough room for three `li` and a few pixels of the fourth.

- Room needed per `li`: 16px(font-size) * 1.2(line-height) + ~3px (inline spacing) + 2 * 20px(top/bottom padding) = ~62px. (Firefox DevTools reports `li.height: 22px` without padding, which proves the calc).
- Total minimum height of a `.slide` = 5 * 62px = 310px.

Without animation requirements, it would be best to use `height: auto` when `touch` gets clicked...

Add `* { outline: 1px dashed }` to you CSS and you will see it happen.

**snippet** without the `<input id="touch">`

```css
* { outline: 1px dashed }

.slide {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .4s ease;
}

.slide li {
  padding: 20px
}

.slide.test1 { height: 310px }
.slide.test2 { height: auto }
```

```html
<h3>original: 200px</h3>
<ul class="slide">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<h3>height: 310px</h3>
<ul class="slide test1">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<h3>height: auto</h3>
<ul class="slide test2">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```